# Why livereload works once?

Tags: html, google-chrome, sublimetext3, livereload

I have installed with Package Control livereload plugin for Sublime Text 3, added `<script>` to html file, downloaded Google Chrome extension LiveReload 2.1.0 enabled Simple Reload in preferences in ST3 and when I type some char in html file I get on save this in the Chrome browser but it works only once